# React rendering images not working

Tags: javascript, image, reactjs, src

not sure if this is the way/best way to do this in React. please could someone comment if there is a better way or how to make this work

I have a simple image component:

```
import React from 'react';

const component = ({image}) => (
  <img src={image} />
)

export default component;
```

and when I use it I pass it this:

```
<Image image={item.product.image}/>
```

and that lives in an object like so:

```
{
    name: 'Rucksack',
    price: '15.00',
    salePrice: '7.00',
    id: 1,
    image: '/data/rucksack.jpg'
  },
```

but when I run it I get the little green image error and the console says:
`http://localhost:8080/data/rucksack.jpg 404 (Not Found)`

anything Im not quite doing right?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with React. Open this address (`http://localhost:8080/data/rucksack.jpg`) in browser, then modify the server and/or address until it works. In the end, fix the code to match what works..

Comment: @xs0 ok yeh that's what im not sure how to do

Comment: well, what software are you using to serve your app? How is it configured? You should probably edit your question, delete everything related to react, add these details and change the title :)

Comment: haha. using webpack

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it is an issue with the image URL. The server returns 404 resonance because it can't find the image. Check whether the image URL is working.

You should be able to access the image with `http://localhost:8080/data/rucksack.jpg`. Check it with a curl command or by using the browser.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use require to make it work with webpack.

You just need to change you image component, and the path now needs to be relative:

```
import React from 'react';

const component = ({image}) => (
  <img src={require(image)} />
)

export default component;
```

You also need to make the path relative (maybe you need to adapt it):

```
{
    name: 'Rucksack',
    price: '15.00',
    salePrice: '7.00',
    id: 1,
    image: '../data/rucksack.jpg'
  },
```